# Smoothing a list of Longitude Latitude Points in Java

Tags: java, coordinates, geo

Im trying to work out how to smooth a big list of longitude latitude points i currently draw a line from point to point and interpolate each point in-between but as i change direction it shows a sharp turn where i would like to smooth this out to a neat curve, but i dont know exactly where the turns are so i need an algorithm to smooth over an average of points.

I have done some research into this already and had a look at the Bezier curve but does not work as i expect, i took the implementation that i found here.
http://sourcecodesforfree.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/33-bezier-curve.html

I cant really find much documentation on how the Bezier Curve algorithm works, or at least not fully understanding how it works.

Comment: please find an Algorithm from this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#Linear_interpolation or you can go with dt = (t - t0) / (t1 - t0) // fraction of time elapsed between t0 & t1
p.x = p0.x + ( dt * (p1.x - p0.x) )  // the point's x is that same fraction between x0 and x1
p.y = p0.y + ( dt * (p1.y - p0.y) )  // ditto, y.

Comment: Are you asking for an alternative to Bézier curves, because they don't satisfy your needs (why not?), or for help with getting your Bézier code to work? The question is too broad if it should cover both.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson bit of both really i cant really tell if my Bezier code is working correctly, as i get some line smoothing but no where near enough what i need, so maybe an alternate method would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
function bspline(lats, lons) {
var i, t, ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy, lat, lon, points;
points = [];
// For every point
for (i = 2; i < lats.length - 2; i++) {
    for (t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.2) {
        ax = (-lats[i - 2] + 3 * lats[i - 1] - 3 * lats[i] + lats[i + 1]) / 6;
        ay = (-lons[i - 2] + 3 * lons[i - 1] - 3 * lons[i] + lons[i + 1]) / 6;
        bx = (lats[i - 2] - 2 * lats[i - 1] + lats[i]) / 2;
        by = (lons[i - 2] - 2 * lons[i - 1] + lons[i]) / 2;
        cx = (-lats[i - 2] + lats[i]) / 2;
        cy = (-lons[i - 2] + lons[i]) / 2;
        dx = (lats[i - 2] + 4 * lats[i - 1] + lats[i]) / 6;
        dy = (lons[i - 2] + 4 * lons[i - 1] + lons[i]) / 6;
        lat = ax * Math.pow(t + 0.1, 3) + bx * Math.pow(t + 0.1, 2) + cx * (t + 0.1) + dx;
        lon = ay * Math.pow(t + 0.1, 3) + by * Math.pow(t + 0.1, 2) + cy * (t + 0.1) + dy;
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon));
    }
}
return points;
```

}

> Above code in JavaScript else logic are same just change bit variables and method as JAVA then check
>   Or
>   please find an Algorithm from this link en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#Linear_interpolation

Comment: Just implemented this in Java, and its the same result as before still getting sharp edges.